# Installation guide for ROS-Kinetic with Python 3.5 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python-3.5, ros

I'm having a ROS-node that uses Python 3.5 and I want to run it on ROS-Kinetic. This is supposed to run on Ubuntu 16.04 with Kernel 4.4.
I've read that it's complicated to match ROS-Kinetic with Python 3 because it's not officially supported...but I've also read that it is possible to do so...
There are several installation guides for specific packages and I've tried some of them but failed everytime.

What I've tried so far:

1) Installed ROS-Kinetic-desktop-full

2) pip3 install rospkg catkin_pkg

3) export PYTHONPATH = /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages

When I'm running catkin_make, the first error appearing says:

> ... ImportError: No module named genmsg ...

Can anyone please write an exact installation guide for making ROS-Kinetic run with Python 3.5 (without a virtual environment) or tell me what's missing in my installation?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to [Some progammer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9540923/some-progammer)'s answer, you could install the packages in global space

```
sudo apt-get install python3-yaml  # you'll also need this
sudo pip3 install rospkg catkin_pkg
```

or add `--user` flag

```
pip3 install --user rospkg catkin_pkg
```

People used Python 3.5 + ROS-Kinetic in Ubuntu before (for example, check out [cozmo_driver](https://github.com/OTL/cozmo_driver#super-hack-to-run-rospy-from-python3)) and it should work according to [REP3](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#kinetic-kame-may-2016-may-2021).

Answer (score 0):

You are not exporting the right folder to PYTHONPATH. Try

```
export PYTHONPATH=/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm definetely gonna try it out! But will it then be able to handle python3-nodes when there is python2 as PYTHONPATH? Or does the pythonpath not influence the ability of which python it's able to compile?